# Jetpack Compose Navigation: Direct navigation to route in a nested graph which is not startDestination

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am working on Jetpack Compose Navigation demo and I have a nested navigation graph with two different nested routes and screens for each nested route:

- Login Graph
- Main Graph

Login Graph has three routes for display three different Screens

- Route "login" for displaying LoginScreen
- Route "register" for displaying RegisterScreen
- Route "recoverPassword" for displaying RecoverPasswordScreen

Main Graph has two routes for these screens

- Route "home" for displaying HomeScreen
- Route "settings" for displaying SettingsScreen

The nested graph creation is called in the *MainActivity.kt*

```
setContent {
        NavigationDemoTheme {

            val navController = rememberNavController()
            SetupNavGraph(navController = navController)
        }
    }
```

The function in the file *NestedNavGraph.kt* looks like this:

```
fun SetupNavGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "login_route")
    {
        loginGraph(navController = navController)
        mainGraph(navController = navController)
    }
}
```

In the file *LoginNavGraph.kt* I have defined the routes and start destination

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.loginGraph(navController: NavController) {
    navigation(startDestination = "login", route = "login_route") {
        composable(route = "login") {
            LoginScreen(navController = navController)
        }

        composable(route = "register") {
            RegisterScreen(navController = navController)
        }

        composable(route = "recover") {
            RecoverPasswordScreen(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}
```

In the file *MainNavGraph.kt* I have defined these two routes and this start destination:

```
 navigation(startDestination = "home", route = "main_route") {

        composable(route = "home") { 
            HomeScreen(navController = navController)
        }

        composable(route = "settings") { 
            SettingsScreen(navController = navController)
        }
    }
```

My questions now is: How can I display the RecoverPasswordScreen from SettingsScreen. I know I can navigate to the "login_route" from the SettingsScreen with but then the startDestination will be displayed, which is the LoginScreen.

```
// shows the LoginScreen because the startDestination in the "login_route" is set to "login"
navController.navigate(route = "login_route")
```

So, how can I directly navigate to the route "recover" in the nested graph route "login_route"? The following "workarounds" are in my mind:

Pass a parameter to the "login_route", for example something with:

```
navController.navigate(route = "login_route?destination=recover")
```

I will then have only a single route as a destination, for example "LoginView". This will change the loginGraph like this:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.loginGraph(navController: NavController) {

    navigation(startDestination = "login_view, route = "login_route/{destination}) {

        composable(
            route = "login_view",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("destination") { defaultValue = "login" },
            )
        ) { backStackEntry ->

            val destination =  backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("destination");

            destination?.let { destination ->  
                LoginView(destination = destination)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The LoginView is composable whichw will have a own NavHost where I can set the startDestination with the query parameter from the previous route:

```
fun LoginView( destination : String = "login"){

    val navController = rememberNavController()
    var startDestination = destination;

    Scaffold ()
    {

        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = startDestination
        ) {

           composable(route = "login") {
             LoginScreen(navController = navController)
           }

           composable(route = "register") {
             RegisterScreen(navController = navController)
           }

           composable(route = "recover") {
             RecoverPasswordScreen(navController = navController) 
           }
    }
}
```

Now  I should be able to call the RecoverPasswordScreen from the SettingsScreen with this:

```
navController.navigate(route = "login_route?destination=recover")
```

Another possibility is to have extra route for the RecoverPassword Screen in the MainGraph defined. Is there any other possibilty to directly acess a route in a nested graph? It would be great if could dynamically change startDestination when routing to "login_route" but I don't know how or if this is even possible.

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution is to use deeplinks defined in the navigation graph - they also work for nested destinations. Then, instead of navigating to the route name, you can use `navController.navigate(deepLinkUri)`

Answer (score 1):

If a screen-level composable is re-used in very different places in my applications, I tend to just give it its own navigation graph, even if it is the only screen inside that graph?

For example, in your specific scenario, you would have your "loginGraph", "mainGraph" and then a "recoverPassword" graph, where the only destination in the "recoverPassword" graph is the `RecoverPasswordScreen`.

This will enable you to navigate to the `RecoverPasswordScreen` from anywhere in your application, whilst still keeping separate nav graphs for most of your flows.

```
fun SetupNavGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "login_route")
    {
        loginGraph(navController = navController)
        recoverPasswordGraph(navController = navController)
        mainGraph(navController = navController)
    }
}

fun NavGraphBuilder.loginGraph(navController: NavController) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = "login",
        route = "login_route"
    ) {
        composable(route = "login") {
            LoginScreen(
                onRecoverPasswordClicked = {
                    navController.navigateTo("recover_password_route")
                }
           )
        }
        ...
    }
}

fun NavGraphBuilder.recoverPasswordGraph(navController: NavController) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = "recoverPassword",
        route = "recover_password_route"
    ) {
        composable(route = "recoverPassword") {
            RecoverPasswordScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

This also works nicely as you might have more screens to add to the recover password flow later - e.g. a `PasswordRecoverySuccessfulScreen()` - and that can just be added to this new graph.

Comment: This is the best answer. From the logic POV, if you have something "global" in your app, something where you can navigate from any place in the app, it needs to be declared on the "global" level. 

Alternative solution could be declare two `navigate { composable{RecoverPasswordScreen} }` but with different "routes" which will make them two independent navigation destinations on the NavGraph, so you can have your own RecoverPasswordScreen in the "Settings" navigation graph branch.

Answer (score -1):

Compose allows you to [(Navigate with arguments)](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation?authuser=1#nav-with-args). This allows you to navigate to what you are calling "nested routes", that is a specific part within a screen.

Now, this is a simple explanation and I could leave you and have you figure it out. But I don't think this would be helpful to you as I think you have implemented your navigation in a difficult manner. Hence why trying to navigate is a bit more complex.

Here is a better way to implement it so that navigation like the one you want(RecoverPasswordScreen from Settings Screen) is easier.

#### Disclaimers

Change anything that's referred to as *Main* to your AppName.

**I have not added all your screens**

### Main Screen class

```
//you could pass in parameters if needed into this constructor
enum class MainScreen(){
//these are your screens
   LogIn(),
   Settings(),
   Recover(),
   Home();

 companion object {
        fun fromRoute(route: String?): MainScreen =
            when (route?.substringBefore("/")) {
                LogIn.name -> LogIn
                Home.name -> Home
                Settings.name -> Settings
                Recover.name -> Recover
                //add the remaining screens
                // a null route resolves to LogInScreen.
                null -> LogIn
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Route $route is not recognized.")
            }
    }

}
```

### Main Activity Class

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MainApp()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainApp() {
    MainTheme {
        val allScreens = MainScreen.values().toList()
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        val backStackEntry = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        // currentScrren user is on good if app is large
        val currentScreen = MainScreen.fromRoute(
            backStackEntry.value?.destination?.route
        )
        //Using scaffold is a good idea
        Scaffold(
           //add topAppBar and all other things here
        ) { innerPadding ->
            MainNavHost(navController = navController, modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding))

        }
    }
}

//Scaffold requires innerPadding so remove if you decide not to use scaffold
@Composable
fun MainNavHost(navController: NavHostController, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = LogIn.name,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        composable(LogIn.name) {
            /**
             Your body for logIn page
            **/

        }
//this is how you will navigate to Recover Screen from settings
        composable(Settings.name) {
            SettingsBody(onClickRecoverScreen = {navController.navigate(Recover.name)})

            }
        }
          composable(Recover.name) {
             /**
             Your body for Recover page
            **/
        }
        composable(Home.name) {
             /**
             Your body for Home page
            **/
        }
        


}
```

### Settings Screen

```
@Composable
fun SettingsBody(
    //this callback is how you will navigate from Settings to RecoverPassword
    onClickRecoverScreen: () -> Unit = {},
) {
    Column(
       //Add your designs for this screen
    ) {
        Button(onClick = {onClickRecoverScreen})
    }
}
```

This is the simplest way (in my opinion) to implement Navigation as you can simply add callbacks to navigate to different places in the app and it is much more testable(if you test ;) ) and scalable. You can also add deep links and use arguments (as mentioned above) to navigate to specific parts of the app (e.g., a specific account in an Accounts Screen)

I highly recommend this [Navigation Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation?authuser=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%3Fauthuser%3D1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-navigation) if you want to understand more.

Comment: Your answer is working but it's not what Google is recommending at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation. 

You only have the routes in one file and when you have 50 routes itÄs getting confusing. 

The Google website says: "Destinations can be grouped into a nested graph to modularize a particular flow in your app’s UI. An example of this could be a self-contained login flow. It is strongly recommended that you split your navigation graph into multiple methods as the graph grows in size. This also allows multiple modules to contribute their own navigation graphs. "

Comment: @xshake is your app large?

Comment: The app is currently not large but it will become quite large. I figured out that the main issues is because I have a bottom bar which has an own NavHost and routing from the bottom bar displayed screens to the other nested routes (for example Login) is not possible. This is because I have  two different navigation controllers with different nodes.

Comment: This does not answer how the one can navigate deep to `navigate` section of the NavGraph, the offered solution even does not have nested graphs, it's a plain graph which is not suitable to large apps.