# How to do Jetpack Compose Navigation for dynamic feature modules?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

Working on Jetpack Compose Navigation with multi module application. Using Kotlin DSL.
We have dynamic feature modules DFM1, DFM2, DFM3.

How to setup navigation graph and navigate between dynamic feature modules.

Comment: @ferdinand  How we can do this with dynamic feature [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71392630/jetpack-compose-navigation-direct-navigation-to-route-in-a-nested-graph-which-i)