# I got error after navigate to specific screen in nested NavGraph

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to navigate from Dashboard Screen that wrapped in MainScreen to trackingGraph. but i got error like below

**The error**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/tracking_root } cannot be found in the navigation graph ComposeNavGraph(0x177b2ebb) route=main_root startDestination={ComposeNavGraph(0xf4c7f07a) route=dashboard_root startDestination={Destination(0x78d845ec) route=home}}
```

**My Root Graph**
The MainScreen() contains bottom navigation graph

```
@Composable
fun RootNavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = RootScreen.Welcome.route,
    ) {
        welcomeGraph(navController)
        authGraph(navController)
        composable(route = RootScreen.Main.route) {
            MainScreen()
        }
        trackingGraph(navController)
    }
}
```

**Main Screen**

```
 @Composable 
fun MainScreen() {
    
        val navController = rememberNavController()
    
        val listThatShowWithBottomNav = listOf(
            ChildScreen.Dashboard.route,
            ChildScreen.Profile.route,
            ChildScreen.Order.route
        )
    
        val currentSelectedScreen by navController.currentScreenAsState()
        val currentRoute by navController.currentRouteAsState()
    
    
        AppScaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.systemBarsPadding(),
            bottomBar = {
                if (currentRoute != null && listThatShowWithBottomNav.contains(currentRoute)) {
                    BottomNavBar(
                        navController = navController,
                        currentSelectedScreen = currentSelectedScreen
                    )
                }
            },
            floatingActionButton = {
                if (currentRoute != null && listThatShowWithBottomNav.contains(currentRoute)) {
                    FloatingActionButton(
                        onClick = { }, contentColor = Color.White,
                        backgroundColor = Blue300,
                        elevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(defaultElevation = 0.dp),
                        modifier = Modifier.size(60.dp)
                    ) {
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_order),
                            contentDescription = "icon order",
                            modifier = Modifier.size(30.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }
    
            },
            backgroundColor = Color.White
        ) {
            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = RootScreen.Dashboard.route,
                route = RootScreen.Main.route
            ) {
                dashboardGraph(navController)
                orderGraph(navController)
                profileGraph(navController)
    
            }
        }
    }
```

**The Code that navigate to specific screen**

```
private fun NavGraphBuilder.dashboardCHILD(navController: NavController) {
    composable(route = ChildScreen.Dashboard.route) {

        DashboardScreen(navController = navController,
            onNavigateToTracking = {

            navController.navigate(RootScreen.Tracking.route)
        },
            onNavigateToFeature = { }) {

        }
    }

}
```

How to navigate from specific screen, let say, from dashboard, to the
tracking screen which is wrapped into TrackingGraph?

Comment: Please check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71392630/jetpack-compose-navigation-direct-navigation-to-route-in-a-nested-graph-which-i
It is not easily possible in Jetpack Compose to directly jump to a specific destination within a nested NavGraph. Do the answers proposed there help you?

Comment: As a follow-up hint, depending on your requirements, have a look at this library, which simplifies navigation with Jetpack Compose: https://github.com/raamcosta/compose-destinations